# Unable to run EXE's from network share

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, windows-server-2019

Before i begin let me inform you that I've already gone through other threads here regarding the same issue, none of them seems to have helped, therefore creating my own.

The issue started recently, by the very least i think it started happening 3 weeks ago. we have a custom build application that is deployed on our Network share, the exe is lightweight program, nothing too heavy. 
The EXE can be ran manually or through our a shortcut but doesn't run either ways, a window about the same size as the app pops up and disappears immediately if you constantly double click on the exe.

All our Client computers are Windows 10 1909 build. All our servers are VMs running on a Hyper-V host and Windows Server 2019 latest version as well. only the Hyper-V Host is Server 2016 and the application runs fine on that server only. 
Infact all other EXEs can be opened through the network share (not on the same server but on a VM) on that 2016 host but none of the exe's open on any other client computer or VM's.
The respective GPO to trust UNC paths is enabled and applied, there are no errors or warning whatsoever when launching any of the exe's, the files just don't open no matter how many times you click on it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about a programming problem, so it would probably be better suited for one of the other StackExchange sites, (maybe ServerFault or SuperUser). But does the application produce any logs that you can investigate? What about the Event Viewer in Windows on the client machine, are there any errors or warnings regarding this specifc application?

Comment: No logs or warning at all and the application developed does log stuff but not until any of the commands are performed so no logging until it is launched and a process is run.